# Does pair production of γ-photons involve mass-energy conversion?

Tags: particle-physics

During pair production of γ - photons, γ – photons (which does not have any rest mass) emits an electron and a positron(both of which have rest mass). How is this possible?

Comment: Best thing I can recommend, if you have not already done so, is read this article and then post a specific question on any part you don't follow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production

Answer (score 6):

First, some terminology: [pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) involves the creation of a particle-antiparticle pair from a gamma photon, while [particle-antiparticle annihilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation) into gamma rays is its reverse process.

As you note, both of these processes change the sum of the rest masses of the constituents, but they conserve the total energy. This is perfectly possible because rest mass is not a conserved quantity in relativity - it is only one of many contributions to the total energy, which does get conserved.

Finally, as @dmckee mentions in a comment, it's also important to note that the invariant mass of the system (i.e. the total mass and energy in the system's rest frame) does remain constant. It's just not always given by the sum of the rest masses of the components.

Comment: When you say *"both of these processes change the amount of rest mass available"* you presumably mean "the sum of the masses of the constituents is changed", which is certainly correct. But it is at least as important that the invariant mass of the system is the same after the process as before it. It's just that the invariant mass of a system is not necessarily the sum of the masses of the parts.

Comment: @dmckee Yeah, I like that wording better. I'll leave the rest of the details attributed to you, though.

Answer (score 1):

Total energy(along with momentum) is conserved in any process and the pair production respects it.
Now note that total energy of a photon is entirely due to its momentum from below, which gets converted into kinetic energy and rest mass energy of particle anti particle pair.

$$E=mc^2=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4}$$

Comment: I disagree with "only." The momentum of the system is also conserved.

Comment: Indeed it is incomplete.But I was referring to the rest mass conservation.